# Using Brushes (mainly dodge and burn) in Aperture 3 while in Full Screen Mode

Tags: aperture

One of the reasons I went to Aperture from iPhoto was that I could easily dodge and burn my photos, which iPhoto doesn't let you do.

I have also been enjoying the full screen mode in aperture, where I will keep the HUD up for my edits.

While doing some edits yesterday, I noticed that the brushes control wasn't available full screen, unless I am missing something. I also couldn't find the red eye removal tool while in full screen either.

Doing searches online was not that helpful, since brushes and full screen were new in Aperture 3, so usually doing a search like 'aperture 3 brushes full screen' usually returns results listing the new features in Aperture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In full screen mode move your mouse to the top of the screen, a toolbar will drop down which has the red eye tool. The is also a button for the inspector hud which is the same as the usual adjustment palette. Brushes work just the same.

Comment: It would have taken forever to find this. I just realized before I posed this question that if you go to the bottom of the screen, the photos in the set will show up.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Henry’s information, here’s a picture to make it more clear:

**The “hidden Toolbar”**

[image: Toolbar]

Don’t miss **The Palette**, it contains interesting options for these brushes:

[image]

**UPDATE** If you want the “Hidden Toolbar” to remain ‘pinned’ while working in full screen, simply touch this…switch onto the *lock* position:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the picture. I know I had moved my mouse to the top but maybe I didn't. Is there a way to pin the toolbar to the top, similar to how you can pin the inspector/adjustments to the side?

Comment: @jmlumpkin You’re welcome. Yes, you can pin the bar by clicking in the “pin the bar thing” (I name it like that because it looks more like an x-plane UI element than an Apple thing). I’ll update the answer with it, but for the record it’s the right-most item, a small switch. Put it in the “down” position and your bar will remain there.

Comment: thank you. The same control I am already using for the adjustments window.